# How To Start Python Script On Bootup

Tags: cron

I have a couple of Python scripts I want to launch at bootup. One is located at the path below.
`/home/my-sickbeard-install/SickBeard.py`
Since Cron has never ever worked for me and nobody on about 5 forums knows how to fix my Cron problem even though it's a pretty much clean install of the OS, I need another method of launching these scripts on bootup. Can someone suggest to me another way I can launch them please?
Note: This is actually for something I'm trying to do a Debian machine. Not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: How is this any form of way a possible duplicate jacob? My question very clearly states about a problem with crontab and how to not use crontab to do this function. That link goes straight onto an answer of "use crontab". Wish I could vote-down your statement.

Comment: @karel, that answer also does not provide the answer to my question as I do not wish to run my program as root. So both your statements are wrong and I get a downvote because you both clearly don't understand my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to `/etc/rc.local`. This can be used to run scripts and programs on system boot which doesn't have their own scripts for runlevels. It will run as `root`

Run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and add your line **before** `exit 0`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

python /home/my-sickbeard-install/SickBeard.py 2>&1 >/dev/null &

exit 0
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>O</kbd> to save and  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Comment: What is the rc local file, and what does it do?

Comment: @johnsmith I updated my answer. My previous attempt doesn't work because `/etc/rc.local` **must** end with `exit 0`

Comment: Hi this does work, however when I reboot now, it won't shutdown because it says "A stop job is running for /etc/rc.local Compatibility (1min 9s/ no limit)". It's effectively just broke my server.

Comment: @johnsmith okay, so this is a long running task. You need to send it into background with `2>&1 >/dev/null &`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks I spotted it. However I just tried it again using the bit of config you put in & the problem still is there.

Comment: You should make sure your script does exit on `SIGTERM` like if you `kill PID` the process. Otherwise your system will wait and send `SIGKILL` after a timeout on shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed this:

```
python-py | echo '/home/my-sickbeard-install/SickBeard.py'
cron -l /home/my-sickbeard-install/SickBeard.py
cron -l -restart
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: cron always says "no crontab for [user]". Nobody knows how to fix it. I won't use cron. If you think you can fix it, please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212703/crontab-error-no-crontab-for-user

Comment: it is only cron not crontab

Comment: Ok I didn't realise there was a difference. I just tried typing $cron -l and it gives an error, bash: cron command not found. It seems that cron or crontab just never work for me.